# Clickable area with low z-index

Tags: html, css

I have found so many topics for this question, but none of those helps for my case.

I have one div with low z-index. There is a button in that div, that should be clickable. But it is not clickable, because of low z-index. I have tried to change z-index for other divs and containers, but I could not find out the right combination.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">        
    <div id="left"> <a href="/" id="logo"> </a>             
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="content_img">
            <img src="http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/office.png">
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div id="docked_div">
        <div class="fb"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/cityrefund"><img src="http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/f.png" style="width:27px; height: 28px; padding-left: 20px;"></a>

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 1004px;
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 249px;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 750px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#logo {
    background: url(../images/logo.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    width: 250px;
    height: 135px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    display:block;
}
#content_img {
    width: 750px;
    height: 300px;
}
#docked_div {
    background: url(http://tax.allfaces.lv/templates/tax/images/mazais_fons.png) no-repeat;
    width: 52px;
    height: 212px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: -37px;
    top: 105px;
    z-index: -1;  **//EDIT HERE!!!!!!!**
}

.fb {
    /*z-index: 1000;*/
}
```

I need to be able to click on FB button. Now when `#docked_div` z-index is set to -1, then `.fb` is not clickable. If I set z-index = 1 to `#docked_div`, then `.fb` is clickable, but then `#docked_div` is on top of the image, it should be under.

Example is seen here (FB button is not clickable): http://jsfiddle.net/vAkXh/7/   **[edit here]**
The full example is here: tax.allfaces.lv (you can see that here FB button is clickable, but it is on top of image, it is not correctly).

Comment: In order for z-index to work, the element must have a position other than static. That is, you must set the position property for the elemnt. As I can see in your .fb class, you have provided only the z-index and not position:relative/absolute.

Comment: seems to work fine for me (in chrome) but I would have increased the z-index of the `docked_div`

Comment: i didn't get what you need :(

Comment: The link is already clickable. Do you want the whole `#docked_div` or `.fb` to be clickable as well?

Comment: So what do u want? :D We can click the fb image. Btw don't forget usage of `alt="what is on that image"` in `<img>` ;) if u want it whole to be clickable then just do this: http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/vAkXh/5/ ?

Comment: Tested on IE7, IE8, FF21 and CH27... I can click FB div in all these.

Comment: I have updated an example. You can see that if #docked_div z-index is -1, then you cannot click. If you set z-index = 1, thenyou can click, but then this #docked_div is on top of #content_img. Also there are some other divs (not only #content_img) I have removed from this example for simplicity, that should be over #dockable_div.

Answer (score -2):

Just add to the #right div :

```
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
```

I tried on http://tax.allfaces.lv/, it should work.

Comment: Please, could you explain a bit more? Should this property go to the inner `div` or to the content `div` (docked)? Because if I apply this property to `#docked_div` I can't click on the icon at all... without this property I can.

Comment: This property is useful if you need to click on a div behind another.
I don't know if it's work for a container.

But, imho you have a conception problem. You shouldn't have negative z-index.
If you can't change but want to force your element to be on top, add a relative of absolute position and add !important to z-index.

(z-index: 1!important;)

Comment: FC: can you explain a bit more for which element to add "relative of absolute position". I need the #docked_div to be under #right div (it is becuase of design issues - the designer created a design so that the left margin of this div should be under the #right div).. Here is a website: tax.allfaces.lv (you can see that now div is clickable but it is on top of the image and it is not correcly()

Comment: I have not noticed, but this doesn't work! docked_div is on top of the right div, but it should be under it, but still clickable.